# Ways to get the middle of a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I've just started learning about Functional Programming, using Haskel.

I'm slowly getting through [Erik Meijer's lectures on Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Lecture-Series-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals-Chapter-1/) (I've watched the first 4 so far) and in the 4th video Erik explains how tail works, and it fascinated me.

I've tried to write a function that returns the middle of a list (2 items for even lengths, 1 for odd) and I'd like to hear how others would implement it in

- The least amount of Haskell code
- The fastest Haskell code

If you could explain your choices I'd be very grateful.

My beginners code looks like this:

```
middle as | length as > 2   = middle (drop 2 (reverse as))
          | otherwise       = as
```

Comment: Did you test your function thoroughly? middle "abcd" = "ba" doesn't seem quite right :).

Comment: I hadn't tested on small lists! back to the drawing board....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Two versions

1. Using pattern matching, [`tail`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Atail) and [`init`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Ainit):

   ```
   middle :: [a] -> [a]
   middle l@(_:_:_:_) = middle $ tail $ init l
   middle l           = l
   ```
2. Using [`length`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Alength), [`take`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Atake), [`signum`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Asignum), [`mod`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Amod), [`drop`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Adrop) and [`div`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Adiv):

   ```
   middle :: [a] -> [a]
   middle xs = take (signum ((l + 1) `mod` 2) + 1) $ drop ((l - 1) `div ` 2) xs
     where l = length xs
   ```

The second one is basically a one-liner (but uses `where` for readability).

Comment: I really like the first one. So short and simple. As an aside; how do back ticks work in Haskell?

Comment: @Matt: thanks :). The backticks convert a binary function to an infix operator. So, `fun :: a -> b -> c` can be called as `fun a b` but also as `a \`fun\` b`.

Comment: It's nicer to say: middle . tail . init $ l

Comment: The first one has a time complexity of O(n^3), which is bad for this kind of operation. You could do it in O(1), see gwerns answer.

Comment: May I ask what role `signum` plays in the second solution? As far as I can see, the result of the modulus will be either `0` or `1` anyway. Or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 17):

Just for your amusement, a solution from someone who doesn't speak Haskell:

Write a recursive function that takes two arguments, a1 and a2, and pass your list in as both of them. At each recursion, drop 2 from a2 and 1 from a1. If you're out of elements for a2, you'll be at the middle of a1. You can handle the case of just 1 element remaining in a2 to answer whether you need 1 or 2 elements for your "middle".

Comment: I like it :D
I might use that in normal programming!

Comment: We seem to agree that Haskell programming is not normal programming :) But glad you liked it.

Answer (score 17):

I don't make any performance claims, though it only processes the elements of the list once (my assumption is that computing `length t` is an O(N) operation, so I avoid it), but here's my solution:

```
mid [] = []                      -- Base case: the list is empty ==> no midpt
mid t = m t t                    -- The 1st t is the slow ptr, the 2nd is fast
  where m (x:_) [_] = [x]        -- Base case: list tracked by the fast ptr has
                                    -- exactly one item left ==> the first item
                                    -- pointed to by the slow ptr is the midpt.
        m (x:y:_) [_,_] = [x,y]  -- Base case: list tracked by the fast ptr has
                                    -- exactly two items left ==> the first two
                                    -- items pointed to by the slow ptr are the 
                                    -- midpts
        m (_:t) (_:_:u) = m t u  -- Recursive step: advance slow ptr by 1, and
                                    -- advance fast ptr by 2.
```

The idea is to have two "pointers" into the list, one that increments one step at each point in the recursion, and one that increments by two.

(which is essentially what Carl Smotricz suggested)

Comment: I would move the pattern match on [] to the `mid` function so that we don't have to test it more than once: `mid [] = []`. Looks good though!

Comment: Functional programming is causing my mind to try and bend in ways that it couldn't before. Thanks for your answer, it's really making me think!

Comment: @jberryman, good point, since that pattern won't be hit in recursion, only in the initial call to mid. I updated the code to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 12):

> I've tried to write a function that returns the middle of a list (2 items for even lengths, 1 for odd) and I'd like to hear how others would implement it in

The right datastructure for the right problem. In this case, you've specified something that only makes sense on a *finite* list, right? There is no 'middle' to an infinite list. So just reading the description, we know that the default Haskell list may not be the best solution: we may be paying the price for the laziness even when we don't need it. Notice how many of the solutions have difficulty avoiding `2*O(n)` or `O(n)`. Singly-linked lazy lists just don't match a quasi-array-problem too well.

Fortunately, we do have a finite list in Haskell: it's called [Data.Sequence](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html).

Let's tackle it the most obvious way: 'index (length / 2)'.

Data.Seq.length is `O(1)` according to the docs. Data.Seq.index is `O(log(min(i,n-i)))` (where I think i=index, and n=length). Let's just call it `O(log n)`. Pretty good!

And note that even if we don't start out with a `Seq` and have to convert a `[a]` into a `Seq`, we may still win. Data.Seq.fromList is `O(n)`. So if our rival was a `O(n)+O(n)` solution like `xs !! (length xs)`, a solution like

```
middle x = let x' = Seq.fromList x in Seq.index(Seq.length x' `div` 2)
```

will be better since it would be `O(1) + O(log n) + O(n)`, which simplifies to `O(log n) + O(n)`, obviously better than `O(n)+O(n)`.

(I leave as an exercise to the reader modifying middle to return 2 items if length be even and 1 if length be odd. And no doubt one could do better with an array with constant-time length and indexing operations, but an array isn't a list, I feel.)

Comment: Thanks gwern. That's a useful explanation. I'll look into Data.Squence.

Comment: Great explanation! The maxim "right datastructure for the right problem" says it all.

Just a side note: O(log n) + O(n) is not obviously better than O(n) + O(n). Both simplify to O(n), so you would have to know the constant factors to really tell which is better.

Comment: Carnieri: I did think about that for a while, but one O(n) cancels out another, leaving log(n) vs n; offhand, I can't think of any non-negative numbers where log2(n) >= n or log10(n) >= n. (Natural logs would be the counterexample, though.)
Given the general fuzziness of Big-O, I think it's safe to assume that the former is better.

Comment: Nope, you can't cancel O(n) terms that way. Otherwise you could reason that O(n) + O(n) is *still* O(n), and then cancel, and conclude that the side with no log term is better! Both algorithms are simply O(n); you need analysis of exactly the things that are ignored in asymptotic analysis to know which is better, so you can't do it from the big-oh terms.

Answer (score 5):

Haskell solution inspired by [Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735146/ways-to-get-the-middle-of-a-list-in-haskell/1735168#1735168).

```
middle = m =<< drop 1
   where m []  = take 1
         m [_] = take 2
         m (_:_:ys) = m ys . drop 1
```

Comment: Don't understand a word of it but it looks nice and concise and appears to reflect the spirit of my algorithm. +1!

Comment: `m =<< drop 1` is the same as `drop 1 >>= m`. Since `drop 1` is a function, the funny-looking instance of `Monad` for `(r->)` applies, so this equals `\r -> m ((drop 1) r) r`, or `\r -> m (drop 1 r) r`. We can write the definition more transparently as `middle r = m (drop 1 r) r`. What does `m` do? Well, `m [] r =  take 1 r`, so if `r` has one element, `m (drop 1 r) r = r`. `m [_] r = take 2 r`, so if `r` has two elements, `m (drop 1 r) r = r`. (cont)

Comment: Otherwise, `m (drop 1 r) r = m (drop 2 (drop 1 r)) (drop 1 r) = m (drop 3 r) (drop 1 r)`. Now we see this is the tortoise-hare approach: the first argument to `m` is the hare and the second is the tortoise.

Comment: May I suggest replacing the last line with `m (_ : _ : ys) = m ys . drop 1` for the sake of symmetry?

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence is a linked list, traversal of this list is the dominating factor of efficiency.  Since we need to know the overall length, we have to traverse the list at least once.  There are two equivalent ways to get the middle elements:

- Traverse the list once to get the length, then traverse it half to get at the middle elements.
- Traverse the list in double steps and single steps at the same time, so that when the first traversal stops, the second traversal is in the middle.

Both need the same number of steps.  The second is needlessly complicated, in my opinion.

In Haskell, it might be something like this:

```
middle xs = take (2 - r) $ drop ((div l 2) + r - 1) xs
          where l = length xs
                r = rem l 2
```

Comment: If the list (and whatever crud comes with it) does not fit in the CPU cache, but around half of it *does*, then the tortoise-hare approach may be faster—conses pulled in by the hare will still be in cache when the tortoise reaches them. That approach also has a potential memory advantage, especially if the list is generated lazily: the tortoise can eat the list as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

F# solution based on Carl's answer:

```
let halve_list l =
    let rec loop acc1 = function
        | x::xs, [] -> List.rev acc1, x::xs
        | x::xs, [y] -> List.rev (x::acc1), xs
        | x::xs, y::y'::ys -> loop (x::acc1) (xs, ys)
        | [], _ -> [], []
    loop [] (l, l)
```

It's pretty easy to modify to get the median elements in the list too:

```
let median l =
    let rec loop acc1 = function
        | x::xs, [] -> [List.head acc1; x]
        | x::xs, [y] -> [x]
        | x::xs, y::y'::ys -> loop (x::acc1) (xs, ys)
        | [], _ -> []
    loop [] (l, l)
```

---

A more intuitive approach uses a counter:

```
let halve_list2 l =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | (_, []) -> [], []
        | (0, rest) -> List.rev acc, rest
        | (n, x::xs) -> loop (x::acc) (n - 1, xs)
    let count = (List.length l) / 2
    loop [] (count, l)
```

And a really ugly modification to get the median elements:

```
let median2 l =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | (n, [], isEven) -> []
        | (0, rest, isEven) ->
            match rest, isEven with
            | x::xs, true -> [List.head acc; x]
            | x::xs, false -> [x]
            | _, _ -> failwith "Should never happen"
        | (n, x::xs, isEven) -> loop (x::acc) (n - 1, xs, isEven)

    let len = List.length l
    let count = len / 2
    let isEven = if len % 2 = 0 then true else false
    loop [] (count, l, isEven)
```

Getting the length of a list requires traversing its entire contents at least once. Fortunately, it's perfectly easy to write your own list data structure which holds the length of the list in each node, allowing you get get the length in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

```
middle xs =
  let (ms, len) = go xs 0 [] len
  in  ms

go (x:xs) i acc len =
  let acc_ = case len `divMod` 2 of
         (m, 0) -> if m  == (i+1) then (take 2 (x:xs))
                                  else acc
         (m, 1) -> if m  == i     then [x]
                                  else acc
  in go xs (i+1) acc_ len

go [] i acc _ = (acc,i)
```

This solution traverses the list just once using lazy evaluation. While it traverses the list, it calculates the length and then backfeeds it to the function:

```
let (ms, len) = go xs 0 [] len
```

Now the middle elements can be calculated:

```
let acc' = case len `divMod` 2 of
...
```

Comment: Of course Suppressingfire's solution is superior in runtime as well as in code size, so forget this one :D

Answer (score 1):

Weird that this perfectly obvious formulation hasn't come up yet:

```
middle []    = []
middle [x]   = [x]
middle [x,y] = [x,y]
middle xs    = middle $ init $ tail xs
```

Answer (score 0):

A very straightforward, yet unelegant and not so terse solution might be:

```
middle :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
middle xs
    | len <= 2 = Nothing
    | even len = Just $ take 2 . drop (half - 1) $ xs
    | odd len = Just $ take 1 . drop (half) $ xs
    where 
          len = length xs
          half = len `div` 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This iterates twice over the list.

```
mid xs = m where
  l = length xs
  m | l `elem` [0..2] = xs
  m | odd l = drop (l `div` 2) $ take 1 $ xs
  m | otherwise = drop (l `div` 2 - 1) $ take 2 $ xs
```

Answer (score 0):

I live for one liners, although this example only works for odd lists.  I just want to stretch my brain!  Thank you for the fun  =)

```
foo d = map (\(Just a) -> a) $ filter (/=Nothing) $ zipWith (\a b -> if a == b then Just a else Nothing) (Data.List.nub d) (Data.List.nub $ reverse d)
```

Comment: Take a look at `Data.List.catMaybes` to get rid of the `map . filter`.

Comment: Meh, it's naive, doesn't work if the list's head and tail share an equal element n-k and k, for n is the number of elements in the list.  Damn.  Aw well it was fun!

Comment: Justice:  I was trying to even do this without nub (just thought about it and it solves a small problem but a larger more hidden one remained a commented about) because it isn't in prelude.  But thank you, I did not know that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a haskeller myself but I tried this one.

First the tests (yes, you can do TDD using Haskell)

```
module Main
where
import Test.HUnit
import Middle
main = do runTestTT tests
tests = TestList [ test1
                 , test2
                 , test3
                 , test4
                 , test_final1
                 , test_final2
                 ]

test1         =     [0]    ~=? middle [0]
test2         =     [0, 1] ~=? middle [0, 1]
test3         =     [1]    ~=? middle [0, 1, 2]
test4         =     [1, 2] ~=? middle [0, 1, 2, 3]
test_final1   =     [3]    ~=? middle [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
test_final2   =     [3, 4] ~=? middle [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And the solution I came to:

```
module Middle
where

middle a = midlen a (length a)

midlen (a:xs) 1 = [a]
midlen (a:b:xs) 2 = [a, b]
midlen (a:xs) lg = midlen xs (lg - (2))
```

It will traverse list twice, once for getting length and a half more to get the middle, but I don't care it's still O(n) (and getting the middle of something implies to get it's length, so no reason to avoid it).

Comment: You actually cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, I like to keep things simple:

```
middle [] = []
middle xs | odd (length xs) = [xs !! ((length xs) `div` 2)]
          | otherwise = [(xs !! ((length xs) `div` 2)),(reverse $ xs) !! ((length xs)`div` 2)]
```

Use of `!!` in Data.List as the function to get the value at a given index, which in this case is half the length of the list.

Edit: it actually works now

Comment: Did you test this code? `length xs == odd` compares an `Int` to a function. `length xs $ \`div\` 2` doesn't even parse.

Comment: I didn't please forgive me. I'll fix it up and it is way too late in the morning to be thinking straight.

Comment: Fixed. I do like simplicity and readability when it comes about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. It was just a quick run up. I'm sure it's not very good.

```
middleList xs@(_:_:_:_) = take (if odd n then 1 else 2) $ drop en xs
    where n = length xs
          en = if n < 5 then 1 else 2 * (n `div` 4)
middleList xs = xs
```

I tried. :)

If anyone feels like commenting and telling me how awful or good this solution is, I would deeply appreciate it. I'm not *very* well versed in Haskell.

EDIT: Improved with suggestions from kmc on #haskell-blah

EDIT 2: Can now accept input lists with a length of less than 5.

Comment: The obvious improvement I can see is that should be able to deal with a list of any length

Comment: It can as of 15 hours ago. I just added the error because anything south of 3 elements is kind of pointless to deal with. How do you deal with a list of 2 elements? I could return 1 and 2 I guess, but I'm not sure why I would.

Comment: Got rid of the error line and added some matches for length 1 and two lists.

Answer (score 0):

I like Svante's answer.  My version:

```
> middle :: [a] -> [a]
> middle [] = []
> middle xs = take (r+1) . drop d $ xs
>  where
>    (d,r) = (length xs - 1) `divMod` 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another *one-line* solution:

```
--
middle = ap (take . (1 +) . signum . (`mod` 2) . (1 +) . length) $ drop =<< (`div` 2) . subtract 1 . length
--
```