# LINQ - selecting second item in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have

`string[] pkgratio= "1:2:6".Split(':');`

```
var items = pkgratio.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

I want to select the middle value and have come up with this. Is this a correct way to select the second value in an IEnumberable?

```
pkgratio.Skip(1).Take(1).First();
```

Comment: related to my first ever question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735146/ways-to-get-the-middle-of-a-list-in-haskell

Comment: Using `First()` implies you are confident that an item will actually be at the position you are attempting to access. If there is any doubt, you may wish to use `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

While what you have works, the most straightforward way would be to use the array's index and reference the second item (at index 1 since the index starts at zero for the first element): `pkgratio[1]`

```
Console.WriteLine(pkgratio[1]);
```

A more complete example:

```
string[] pkgratio = "1:2:6".Split(':');

for (int i = 0; i < pkgratio.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(pkgratio[i]);
```

With an `IEnumerable<T>` what you have works, or you could directly get the element using the [`ElementAt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
// same idea, zero index applies here too
var elem = result.ElementAt(1);
```

Here is your sample as an `IEnumerable<string>`. Note that the `AsEnumerable()` call is to emphasize the sample works against an `IEnumerable<string>`. You can actually use `ElementAt` against the `string[]` array result from `Split`, but it's more efficient to use the indexer shown earlier.

```
var pkgratio = "1:2:6".Split(':').AsEnumerable();
Console.WriteLine(pkgratio.ElementAt(1));
```

Comment: Worked with Linq for years now, and have never used ElementAt().  Busy writing some tests and needed it.  Great simple answer

Comment: Same here +1 for the ElementAt, now using ElementAtOrDefault too

Answer (score 58):

I don't think you need to `.Take(1)`.

```
pkgratio.Skip(1).First()
```

Answer (score 24):

`pkgratio.ElementAt(1);` for your scenario.

However, your method is only applicable if you were using some data that implemented `IQueryable` or you needed to take a range of items starting at a specific index eg:

`pkgratio.Skip(5).Take(10);`

Answer (score 20):

Well, the `Take(1)` isn't strictly necessary if you're going to just `First()` it, so I might go with

```
pkgratio.Skip(1).First();
```

However, that `First()` will throw an exception if there no value, so you might want to try `FirstOrDefault()` and then check for null.