# How to read only the second line of a .txt file?

Tags: c#

To read the first line of a .txt file in a wpf application, we can use this line of code:

```
string line1 = File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").First(); // gets the first line
```

But now, how could i read just the second line of my file?

Comment: `File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").Take(2).Last()`; `File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").Skip(1).First()`;...

Comment: `File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: `File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").Skip(1).Take(1)` preserves the enumerable type. That makes the code more refactorable.

Comment: @Mahmoud - `System.String` has a split function already.

Comment: @Mahmoud - Just as a learning point for you, one of the disadvantages with the answer you had posted was requiring reading the entire file, which could be 100,000+ lines, [ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) is an IEnumerable that does not require loading the entire file. then splitting the lines and then finding the second line.

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks @pstrjds for mentioning this! Reading the official documentation reveal things that one didn't notice. Just like this small but important detail. It was stupid answer indeed!

Comment: While I do not expect SO to have questions for every possible "first,second, third, forth,..." apparently at least "second" is answered - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+linq+second gives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701135/linq-selecting-second-item-in-ienumerable,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Skip(1)` to read the second line. Use `FirstOrDefault()` to avoid an error when the file is empty, or has only one line:

```
var line2 = File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```